# Error while importing a csv file in the admin

Tags: magento-1.7, module, extensions, import, csv

My project had an extension called **webshopapps product matrix**

Which was copied from another project and had been configured . But now when I replace it with the new extension by placing its files and folders in its place, it shows error as :

> "*An error occurred while saving this configuration: Invalid Product
>   Matrix File Format Array*"

in the admin section while importing a csv file.
What should I do ?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the developer of this extension?

Comment: What do you mean with "new extension"? Did you purchase an updated version? Then contact Webshopapps support. They are nice and helpful as long as you don't pirate their stuff.

Comment: yes, @fschmengler. I have to consult with the support team of webshopapps.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Export a .csv file from your extension and see how you should build the .csv file you want to import. Copy the format.

Answer (score 0):

Have you resolved this issue? I experienced similar issue so I figured I would share what worked for me.

If you search the extension code for the exception message "Invalid ProductMatrix File Format", you'll see above the exception you should have the following condition:

```
if ($csvCount < 13 || $csvCount > 17....
```

In my case, I had 17 columns, one was not default to the extension. I removed that column giving me a total of 16, imported the sheet successfully. Hope that helps!